# Launching to a level other than root in UINavigationController, from a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, interface-builder

Is it possible to launch an app to a specific level of a navigation stack using a storyboard?

I'm looking to recreate the model employed by Mail.app, where the app launches into the Inbox, but this is actually one level down the navigation stack, and tapping the back button takes you to the root...

[image: Inbox]
[image: Mailboxes]

I understand how this can be done via code, i.e. instantiating the navigation controller within the app delegate and then manually pushing the view controller(s) to create the desired stack, but I'd really like to know if there's a way to achieve the same using storyboards.

Comment: You have to do it in code. The code can fetch the view controllers from the storyboard and you can use that to set up your navigation stack and set the navigation controller as the root

Comment: But you want to do this during a particular event/action only. So you need to check it in didfinshlaunchingwithoptions and use setviewcontrollers in navigationcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is because you need to instantiate your navigation controller at some point that will house your view controllers, and if you do this through storyboards the best you can do is set the navigation controller to be the entry point.

However, it is pretty straightforward to do from code. If your navigation controller has two view controllers where `ViewControllerOne` pushes to `ViewControllerTwo`, then you can just can just push to the second one without an animation as follows:

```
navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: false)
```

And the user will be one level deep in the navigation controller.